# How to delete a record from database on click of button using JQuery in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to delete a record from database on click of delete button using JQuery in codeigniter. Here is my code.

```js
$("#project").on("click", ".dltbtn", function() {
  $("#cur_del").val($(this).attr("data-id"));
});

$("#del_yes").click(function() {
  alert('hello');
  var id = $("#cur_del").val();
  if (id !== "") {
    $.post("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/Project/delete", {
      id: id
    }, function() {
      $("#tr_" + $("#cur_del").val()).parent().parent().remove();

    });
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dltbtn" data-toggle="modal" 
data-id="<?php echo $row->id ?>" 
data-target="#myModal2" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></button>
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting

Comment: There is no any error occured. but when i click on delete button. one model will open for confirmation. and if user click "yes" the record will not delete.. that the problem.

Comment: I think you have not given full code, eg there is no element with id cur_del from where id value is fetched

Comment: Provide your controller and model also

Comment: model:   public function delete($id)
 {
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->delete('sitemanager_project');
  return true;
 }

Comment: controller:  public function delete($id)
 {
  if ($this->auth->isLoggedIn()) {
   if($this->Project_model->delete($id))
   {
    redirect('Project/index');
   }
  }
  else redirect('index/login');
 }

Answer (score 0):

I think the post request you're making isn't being generated properly as the whole php thing is in a string. Try this and check in network that if it is really sending a request and getting into it's success callback.

```
$("#del_yes").click(function() {
  var id = $("#cur_del").val();
  if (id !== "") {
    $.post(<?php echo site_url(); ?> + "/Project/delete", {
        id: id
    }, function() {
        console.log('Delete success at server end. Now removing from html');
        $("#tr_" + id).parent().parent().remove();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The above answer you gave is not working.. please help